# Resize an IplImage in ruby-opencv

Tags: ruby, opencv

I'm using [ruby-opencv](https://github.com/ryanfb/ruby-opencv) to do some image processing. I have an IplImage object that I need to resize. Calling the resize method on that object returns a CvMat object. How do I convert that CvMat object into an IplImage object? Alternatively, is there another way to resize the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the ruby-opencv wrapper. The resize method in CvMat (from which IplImage is inherited in the C++ library) was incorrectly determining the type of the Ruby class to return (i.e., it was returning CvMat instead of IplImage when resize was called on an IplImage). This has been fixed in recent forks of ruby-opencv. For example: https://github.com/ser1zw/ruby-opencv

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) (ImageMagick) for general image manipulation.  It is specifically built to do things like resize images and has a whole host of other features.  Highly recommended!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, RMagick is great, and I've used it in other situations. The problem is that resizing is only one step in the process (face detection and recognition being two other steps in the sequence, with the former happening before the resize and the latter afterwards). Would prefer not to have to convert the image data from something opencv understands into something RMagick understands and then back again.